# Why Beautiful Soup Ignoring CDATA

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup for yahoo weather API (python 2.7):

```
url = 'http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2344116'
page=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

But after this, in parsed url, there is not any CDATA. Why Beautiful Soup ignores this? How can I prevent ignoring the CDATA?

in xml:

```
<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/11.gif"/>
```

in parsed page:
    [image]

And as you see, there CDATA is lost.

Comment: What makes you think it is ignoring the CDATA section? The section is included, as *text*.

Comment: I just ran your code and the CDATA is all there.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Before I overlooked the `yweather`-part. Why not use that one? BeautifulSoup can parse it much more easily. For CDATA you will need some regex magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDATA section is *not* ignored; it is just treated the way a CDATA section *should* be treated, as *text*:

```
>>> print soup.select('description:nth-of-type(2)')[0].text

<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/11.gif"/><br />
<b>Current Conditions:</b><br />
Light Rain Shower, 59 F<BR />
<BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR />
Sun - Rain/Wind. High: 63 Low: 57<br />
Mon - Rain/Wind. High: 60 Low: 53<br />
Tue - PM Showers. High: 58 Low: 55<br />
Wed - Mostly Cloudy. High: 64 Low: 57<br />
Thu - Rain. High: 63 Low: 55<br />
<br />
<a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Istanbul__TR/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/TUXX0014_f.html">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR/><BR/>
(provided by <a href="http://www.weather.com" >The Weather Channel</a>)<br/>
```

You can parse that section as a separate page instead:

```
>>> description_soup = BeautifulSoup(soup.select('description:nth-of-type(2)')[0].text)
>>> description_soup.img
<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/11.gif"/>
```

Note that since this is a *XML feed* you are parsing, consider using the XML mode (requires `lxml` to be installed):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'xml')
```

or (much) better still, use [`feedparser`](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/) to parse RSS feeds.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want the CDATA so badly? From what I can see the same data is in a much more structured way a few lines down:

```
In [28]: soup.findAll('yweather:forecast')
Out[28]: 
[<yweather:forecast day="Sun" date="26 Oct 2014" low="57" high="63" text="Rain/Wind" code="12">
 </yweather:forecast>,
 <yweather:forecast day="Mon" date="27 Oct 2014" low="54" high="61" text="Rain/Wind" code="12">
 </yweather:forecast>,
 <yweather:forecast day="Tue" date="28 Oct 2014" low="56" high="59" text="Rain" code="12">
 </yweather:forecast>,
 <yweather:forecast day="Wed" date="29 Oct 2014" low="57" high="63" text="AM Showers" code="39">
 </yweather:forecast>,
 <yweather:forecast day="Thu" date="30 Oct 2014" low="55" high="62" text="Light Rain" code="11">
 <guid ispermalink="false">TUXX0014_2014_10_30_9_00_EEST</guid>
 </yweather:forecast>]
```

Comment: You are right, but I have to use image because of my boss request ;)